# Java/Android Dead Connection not being detected

Tags: java, android

When I try to send data on the lingering connection, it nevers arrives on the server nor is any error detected on the print writer. This applies to the heartbeat system too.
I have a semi-heartbeat system running. The point of it was to check the "out" error if it happens, but it never does. I have setKeepAlive on for both the app and the server, I am checking out.checkError(), nothing is detecting a lingering connection.
With or without keep alive the same thing happens.
Socket Creation (takes place in a thread):

```
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

Heart Beat System (also threaded):

```
    public void heartbeat(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(connected == true){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
                handlerObject.sendMessage(String.valueOf((char) 1));
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Send Message is defined as:

```
        public void sendMessage(String data){
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());//, true);
                out.println(data + "\r\n");
                out.flush();
                if(out.checkError()) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                try{
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception z){

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be firewall blocking the traffic on sever ,please check by turning off firewall on sever or adding appropriate rule (since you are facing no error so it might be that firewall blocking traffic)

Comment: It's not. The connection works fine. It just eventually becomes unresponsive and no errors are thrown on the application side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to use socket.setSoTimeout(milliseconds); and have the server send a heart beat a few seconds before that. If the client doesn't recieve a heartbeat before then it it will timeout. I can now catch that exception and reconnect.